# Redash not caching the queries

Tags: redash

I am not able to see query being cached in ReDash. I used the ami version provided on their website for self hosting, updated it to the latest version and fired few queries on athena, but everytime it queries Athena and fetches result.

All the configuration are default. Neither I can find out anything from the logs
Please help

Answer (score 0):

It caches results if you were to add an Athena visualization to a dashboard.

If the Athena query takes 1 minute to run, and you schedule a 10 minute refresh... it will cache the results for 10 minutes -- but only be cached when you're viewing the dashboard. So if you share the dashboard link, they don't have to wait 1 minute for it to run the query live.